Finding the function $g(t)$ given its Laplace transform $F(1/s)$
I am trying to find a function g(t) given that its Laplace transform is F(1/s), where F(s) is the Laplace transform of another function f(t).
I know that if f(t) has the Laplace transform F(s), then f(at) has the Laplace transform (1/a) * F(s/a), where a > 0.
I tried to apply this  by setting a = 1/s.
However, I think I might need to use the inverse Laplace transform, but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.
Can someone please help me understand how to find g(t) given that its Laplace transform is F(1/s)? A step-by-step explanation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4689472/622884
